# Electron WebRequest events produce UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Invalid url pattern

Tags: node.js, electron, webrequest

I'm trying to leverage the [WebRequest](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-request) `onBeforeSendHeaders` API. But I'm not having any luck getting it to trigger. As an experiment I tried the other APIs and I similarly see no activity.

Is there anything obviously wrong with my setup. My code looks like

```
const view = new BrowserView({
  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: false,
    partition: LOGIN_PARTITION,
    enableRemoteModule: true
  }
})
....
view.webContents.session.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders(filter, (details, callback) => {
  logger.info(`onBeforeSendHeaders called for ${details}`)
  details.requestHeaders['My-User-Agent'] = 'MyAgent'
  callback({ requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders })
})
....
view.webContents.loadURL(url.href)
```

I've also noticed an unexpected issue. Namely on the [documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-request) it sets a filter like

```
urls: ['https://*.github.com/*', '*://electron.github.io']
```

but for me this produces an error, namely

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Invalid url pattern *://electron.github.io: Empty path.

I'm using an old version of Electron (`10.1.5`) and NodeJS (`v10.24.1`). I'm wondering if they are causing issues.

### Update

Created a repo to demonstrate this issue at https://github.com/sregger/electron-webrequest

Here I'm using Electron 16 and NodeJS 16

Comment: Are you reading a new version of the documentation and applying it to an older version of Electron? If so, that would explain.

Comment: It looks like the documentation was created 6 years and looks roughly the same. See http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/electron.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/docs/api/web-request/history.html. I've also created a separate project based on Electron and NodeJS 16 with what looks like the same issue.

Comment: You could try just `https://electron...` and be done with it, or dig in deeper and find out why. I haven't seen a spec like that before, so maybe it was wishful thinking on the part of the documentation, or a feature that needs to be enabled somehow.

Comment: That's what I am beginning to suspect. But my bigger problem is the lack of invocations. I'm passing in `null` which should bypass the filter, and all address should invoke the function. But this is not happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the issue, which I had not included in the sample above. The problem was

```
const filter = null
```

which I put in place because using `undefined` throws

```
(node:831) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Must pass null or a Function
```

Based on the following documentation

> The filter object has a urls property which is an Array of URL patterns that will be used to filter out the requests that do not match the URL patterns. If the filter is omitted then all requests will be matched.

I assumed the entire object should be `undefined`, then `null` due to the above. Instead it should be

```
const filter = {
      urls: []
    }
```

When `null` is used no url matches. When an empty array is used all urls match.